# Why GWT fileupload does not work on server?

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, file-upload

I have to upload an image on server with my application written in gwt.
I have created a servlet that do the job. 
On client side I use fileupload to make the request.
On localhost it works fine but when I deploy the application on my server the client can't call the servelet and I have no result form the uploading process.

I have tried this:

```
formPanel.setAction(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "mygym/datiEserciziImgService"+"?idEsercizio="+id);
```

and this:

```
formPanel.setAction(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "datiEserciziImgService"+"?idEsercizio="+id);
```

but with no result.

Here is the mapping in the web.xml:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>datiEserciziImgService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>it.mygym.server.service.exercises.ExercisesServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>datiEserciziImgService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/mygym/datiEserciziImgService</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Here is my servlet code:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
    MultipartRequest multi;
    File img = null;
    File imgEnd = null;
    try {
        multi = new MultipartRequest(req, ".");
        ExerciseDto dto = new ExerciseDto();
        UserDto utente = (UserDto)req.getSession().getAttribute(ISessionConstants.USER_LOGGED_IN);
        dto.setUserCreated(utente.getId());
        dto.setUserLastUpdate(utente.getId());
        Integer idEsercizio  = Integer.parseInt(multi.getParameter("idEsercizio"));
        ExerciseServerDto dtoServer = new ExerciseServerDto();
        dtoServer.setExercise(dto);

         img = multi.getFile("startFile");
        dtoServer.setImg(img);
        imgEnd = multi.getFile("endFile");
        dtoServer.setImgEnd(imgEnd);

        _log.error(new StringBuilder("IMMAGINE SERVER estensione").append(img.getName()));

        res.setContentType("text/html");
        String dbKey = (String)req.getSession().getAttribute(ISessionConstants.DB_KEY);
        ExerciseDelegate delegate = new ExerciseDelegate(dbKey);

        delegate.saveImage(dtoServer,idEsercizio);
        res.getOutputStream().print("OK");
        res.getOutputStream().flush();

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        _log.error("Errore durante il salvataggio dei dati esercizio", e1);
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        _log.error("Errore durante il salvataggio dei dati esercizio", e);
        try {
            res.getOutputStream().print("KO");
            res.getOutputStream().flush();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            _log.error("Errore durante il salvataggio dei dati esercizio", e1);
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    } finally {
        if (img != null) 
            img.delete();
        if(imgEnd != null)
            imgEnd.delete();
    }
}
```

And here is the error that I got:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not writable: .
        at com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest.<init>(MultipartRequest.java:219)
        at com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest.<init>(MultipartRequest.java:110)
        at com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest.<init>(MultipartRequest.java:90)
        at it.mygym.server.service.exercises.ExercisesServlet.doPost(ExercisesServlet.java:32)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
```

How can I avoid this strange behaviour?

Comment: Do you see an error in a browser or in your server logs when you submit the form?

Comment: No error in the browser, no error in the catalina.out file and no error in my server log file.
In the method doPost of the servlet I write some information in a log file. But when I submit the form nothing happens

Comment: The form cannot fail silently. Do you get a 200 response?

Comment: This is what I get in the browser console after inspect element: POST http://188.226.139.162:8080/MyGym/mygym/datiEserciziImgService?idEsercizio=19 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Then you must see an error in your server logs.

Comment: I have added extended information to the question with the error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code you are using constructor MultipartRequest(ServletRequest request,String saveDirectory) where you have specified "." as save directory. As per error message it is clear that save directory is not writable. Please check it again on server or replace it with any absolute path on server.